# How to divide item stack in MC PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been struggling with this for a while and couldn’t find a clear answer online so I thought I’d post it since I couldn’t find a correct answer anywhere.

How can I divide a stack in my inventory without switching to classic mode? Unable to right click or hold shift since it is on a smartphone. Some answers I found said something about a coin icon on the left but I don’t see it.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to your own question, however, could you edit your question to be more... questiony?

Comment: Thanks! Updated it to remove the answer part and describe what I was looking for before I stumbled across the functionality.

Answer (score 10):

To divide a stack press and hold on it until a green bar starts filling right above the item. The amount the green bar fills is the amount that is being selected. If half the bar is filled then half the stack is selected. Release the hold when the green bar fills to your desired amount. Tap an empty space in your inventory to move the selected items to the new slot.